# save check box state in android after back button clicked

Tags: android

i am using check box for saving data in database .if it is checked then app redirecting to other screen by saving data after that if i click on device back button then app showing it is not checked.how can i fix this issue?
here i am placing code

```
public void joinLisn(){
    String shareProfileType2=Constants.PROFILE_SHARE_ALL;
    String accessToken = null;
    DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    DatabaseUtility dao = new DatabaseUtility(helper);
    try {
        accessToken = dao.getAccessToken();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
        return;
    }

    if(accessToken == null || accessToken.length() == 0){
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
        return;
    }

    Map<String , String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
    params.put(Constants.ACCESS_TOKEN_PARAM, accessToken);
    params.put(Constants.LISN_ID_PARAM, id);
    params.put(Constants.PROFILE_TYPE_PARAM,shareProfileType2);

    Status status = null;
    try {
        status = Utils.joinLisn(params, this);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(12);
        return;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(11);
        return;
    }

    if(status == null){
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
    } else if(status.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.SUCCESS)){
        try {   
            Intent lisnDetailIntent = new Intent(this, LisnDetailTabView.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            Bundle bundleObj = new Bundle();    
            bundleObj.putString("id", id);
            bundleObj.putString("RSVP","In");
            lisnDetailIntent.putExtras(bundleObj);
            startActivityForResult(lisnDetailIntent,0);
            overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);    
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(8);
        } catch(Exception ex) {}
    } else{
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(2);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused on your problem. Is it that the data isn't being saved in the DB or the checkbox isn't staying checked when you return?

Comment: No data is not saved in DB

Comment: Question is unclear. Can you paste screen shots (more easy to understand instead of a wall of text).

Answer (score 0):

Override the onbackpressed to trigger your function to save the states.

```
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //Do your db saving here
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your app is redirecting to other app, your app will be put to background. Make use of [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) and [onRestoreInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) to save and restore the checkbox state.

Comment: no other apps rendering here ,problem is if check box is checked then app redirecting to next screen then if i click on back button it is is going to previous screen but the check box state is not saving ,check box state not saving it is the only problem